# How to use collation, character_set of connection, database and server to avoid illegal mix of collation error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I have server started with character-set-server=latin1

> [mysqld] character-set-server=latin1

The client I am using for connection fires

> SET NAMES UTF8

As the first query after connection.

Database used also uses latin1 charset and collation lattin_swidish_ci.

But for some of my stored procedure throws illegal mix of collation error on calling them.

here are different character set and collation.

> character_set_client    --     utf8
>   character_set_connection  --   utf8
>   character_set_database   --    latin1
>   character_set_filesystem  --   binary
>   character_set_results   --     utf8
>   character_set_server    --     latin1
>   character_set_system    --     utf8
>   character_sets_dir      --     C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\
>   collation_connection --  utf8_general_ci
>   collation_database  --  latin1_swedish_ci
>   collation_server    --  latin1_swedish_ci

So my question is how to use different charecter set and collation variables to avoid this illegal mix of collation error.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check `character_set_client`, `collation_connection` and `Database Collation` from [13.7.5.11 SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-create-procedure.html).

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is not related to syntax. It is related to how to set connection collation to avoid illegal mix of collation problem.

Comment: My comment is not related to syntax, my comment is related to the values collation assigned to the stored procedure when it was created.